# Object in pose mode does not translate

Tags: animation, transforms, nla-editor, dopesheet

I am doing this super tutorial ([NLA editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDOFg2spySg)), in which we animate an object using armatures.

As mentioned in the image below (23:23 in video), I try to translate the object to create some keyframes for the pelvis. I select the pelvis and I move it by hitting <kbd>G</kbd>, but I can't see the translation. However, we can remark that the dx, dy, and dz are changing!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have to deconnect pelvis from other armatures

Comment: As you don't appear have any constraints, I would look at the locks under the Transform Locks panel.